# Definition of "genomic adaptation"

Tags: evolution, molecular-evolution, genomes, adaptation

I have encountered the term `genomic adaptation` in some literature (for example [Sikkink et al. 2017](https://bmcgenomics.biomedcentral.com/articles/10.1186/s12864-017-3787-2)). I am struggling to parse the term, and I have not been able to find a definition for it.

Is `genomic/genome adaptation` the changes accrued by the genome as a result of evolution?

Or does it refer to some sort of active response by the genome to a particular environment upon introduction (of the organism) to said environment?

Comment: From glancing at the introduction it seems like a pretentious way of saying *genetic*. They are talking about mutations in genes. Genes are in genomes. Hence, make it sound complicated and different to disguise the fact that it is not. But the genome is in the organism and the organism is in the ecosystem, so why stop there. (But please don't.)

Comment: @David seems like you're right. So much for rigor and precise terminology.